# How to remove unwanted root element from XML using JAXB?

Tags: xml, jaxb, tags

How can I remove unwanted root element  from the XML that is being generated through JAXB?

What I need is

[image]

below is the code for Pojo classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="empType", propOrder={ "name", "age", "deptt"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "")
public class EmpType {


EmpType () {}

public EmpType (String name, String age, String deptt ) {

    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.deptt=deptt;

}

  @XmlElement(name="name", required=true)
  protected String name;
  @XmlElement(name="age", required=true)
  protected String age;
  @XmlElement(name="deptt", required=true)
  protected String deptt;

      ... getter / setters

}



  @XmlAccessorType(value=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name="employeesType", propOrder={"emp"})

 public class EmployeesType
{
@XmlElement(required=true)
protected List<EmpType> emp;
protected String prolog;

public EmployeesType()
{
}

public List<EmpType> getEmp()
{
    if(emp== null)
    {
        data = new ArrayList<EmpType>();
    }
    return emp;
}

getter/setter for prolog
}
```

Is there a way where I can remove the  Emp  root element that is appearing from Employee class?

I tried using XMLRootElement (name ="") in Employee class but  it didn't help me in removing  Emp tag.

Comment: Please always supply data as text, not an image. Text is the most useful format to supply data in, as it works with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines, whereas images work with none of these. Help readers to help you! Format XML in Stack Overflow using the block formatting tool, so that it is readable (and visible).

Comment: Just don't put the root element on the generic structure you don't want included in the XML? Seems simple enough. Put the root on the employee list, if possible. Or just remove the specific tags after generation.

Comment: @halfer : Sorry , I spent a lot of time in formatting of XMl but it  didnt appear  properly . hence pasted image . All tags were getting disappeared when used blockquote.

Comment: @G_V tried removing XMLRootElement  annotation . it  didnt help .

Comment: @summary: it simply needs code formatting, as you've done with your code. Would you make that change now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the xml you want:

```
<Employees>
    <prolog>test prolog</prolog>
    <name>employeeOne</name>
    <age>24</age>
    <deptt>store</deptt>
    <name>employeeTwo</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <deptt>store</deptt>
</Employees>
```

Name, age and department are not part of a common element. So you should have your POJOs like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"prolog", "employeeDetails"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Employees")
public class Employees {


    @XmlElement(name="prolog", required=true)
    protected String prolog;
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name="name", type = Name.class),
            @XmlElement(name="age", type = Age.class),
            @XmlElement(name="deptt", type = Department.class),
    })
    private List<EmployeeDetail> employeeDetails;

}
```

And Name:

```
public class Name implements EmployeeDetail {
    @XmlValue
    private String name;
}
```

Age:

```
public class Age implements EmployeeDetail {
    @XmlValue
    private int age;

}
```

And Department:

```
public class Age implements EmployeeDetail {
    @XmlValue
    private int age;

}
```

The common interface EmployeeDetail does not do much:

```
public interface EmployeeDetail {
}
```

With these POJOs you will be able to marshal/unmarshal the xml you specified (skipped `<pre>`) for convenience/speed.

Comment: my apologies, the formatting of the classes' source code in the response seems off, will try to fix it

Comment: Thank you mart for the answer  . Can you please also help me in understanding the  answer at another post  here [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348006/jaxb-marshalling-a-variable-list-of-elements-with-the-same-name ] . It seems like  the user here was able to  fix it without  writing too much code  . Thanks for your  help Mart .

Comment: when i tried the approach stated in that link , i kept  @xmlValue  in all the properties , exception came  like >> only one XMLValue allowed.

Comment: There is less code because he has less elements. But if you would like less code, you could also avoid creating Name, Age and Department and just have the Employees class. Check update

Comment: I am still unable to understand  . But  thanks much  for the efforts for answering it . Best Regards.

Comment: I see. let me try that  once . Thanks Mart .

Comment: Just updated. Maybe I did not understand your question. What do you mean without writing too much code? Please try the examples I gave you and see if it works

Comment: With the updated approach i got the  XML ::                           
     <prolog>test prolog</prolog>
    <deptt>empone</deptt>
    <age>2</age>
    <deptt>deptt1</deptt>
    <deptt>emptwo</deptt>
    <age>3</age>
    <deptt>deptt2</deptt>    Seems like it is taking  String.class and overwriting deptt with name . First approach is accurate but  i am not  sure how to store data in that .

Comment: mmm yes didn't think about that. From POJO to xml could have a problem deciding which xml element applies to String. Okay so we go with first approach only. What do you mean with "how to store data in it"?

Comment: removed update to not cause confusion with an approach that does not work

Comment: Data is coming from DB . So it is like ArrayList <EmployeeList> list = new ArrayList<EmployeeList>(); while(Rs.next())list.add( new Emp(rs.getString(name), rs.getString(age), rs.getString(Deptt) ) ;  return new Employees(list) ; ..........With  separate class approach .... i will have to create separate object for each class and then add to list ....hence lot of code .

Comment: As I understand what you try to do, for each loop then you would create 3 objects and execute three adds to the list. Saying about lots of code is very subjective and depends on context. What I can tell you is that with this xml, you need these POJOs to be able to marshal/unmarshal

Comment: I am able to acheive  the desired XML format  with first approach . Perfectly . The only  thing that is taking me aback is whiel adding to list , i need to create  several objects and then add to it .  in real time scenario  more fields may appear  . But anyway ,  i understood the  concept . Appreciate your efforts.